# How much memory / CPU to allocate to Redis instance?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, redis

I am looking to deploy a Redis instance to Kubernetes cluster.

In Kubernetes official website [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/), they use the following yaml configuration for example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-master
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
      role: master
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: master
        image: k8s.gcr.io/redis:e2e  # or just image: redis
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

Is 100m CPU and 100Mi of memory a good figure to aim for, when using a Redis instance for caching purposes? What should be the limit be set to?

Comment: try load test this and then only you can define the request and limits per container

Comment: Run the pod in a burstable mode for 2 weeks and monitor your memory and cpu consumption. Then set the requests and limits set little greater than the requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no proper answer to your question. Everything depends on your needs in this scenario.

You have to consider resources on your node, your [resource requests/limits](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits), will you use [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) or [VPA](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler), it's on local environment or on cloud environment, how many pods will be deployed on this node, what you will cache, etc.

### Background

In your `Deployment` you set only `requests` so `redis` pod will alwyas have allocated at least `CPU: 100m` and `RAM: 100Mi`. As no `limits` were specified, it might use more and more resources till some errors might occur due to lack of resources (for example it can `terminate` pods without specified `requests`).
Please keep in mind that others pods which was deployed with `Kubernetes` also have some specific `requests`/`limits` like `kube-proxy` or `kube-dns`, etc.

To check current resource usage of your nodes you can use commands:

```
$ kubectl top nodes
NAME                                       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-55c97a92-m2bb   61m          6%     718Mi           25%
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-55c97a92-s907   108m         11%    748Mi           26%
```

If you will `describe` node using `kubectl describe node <NodeName>` you can check node total resources in `Capacity` section and resources which are already used by kubernetes in `Allocatable`. So `Capacity` - `Allocatable` is value of your free resources in this specifc moment (it might be changed due to `requests`/`limits`).

As addition, you can check artice with [Redis Request/limits](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-limits-requests/).

### Conclusion

`Redis` pod can be deployed with those `requests: 100m and 100Mi`. As there is no `limits` set, `Redis` pod might use more and more resources which can cause to termination of other pods. If this node will be dedicated only for `Redis` pod, you can use maximum available resources, value of `Capacity` - `Allocatable`. Now, you can set limit to half of the `node resources`, and later change it depends on results. If pod reached `limits` you can change it to higher values, if opposite, you can change to lower values.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your scenario. If redis is used a lot and it should cache a lot, possibly 100m memory is too less.

Possibly you can use some tools to monitor your redis and see what it really needs.

```
kubectl top pods
```

shows you the current usage of the pod. Give it a stress test and you will see how much it needs. Better if you have something like prometheus or other monitoring tools, which can also tell you stats about evictions and other behaviour.

Further i would go for the redis helm charts from bitnami. It allows you to configure your redis in an easy way by setting values or a custom values file. Those are also production proven.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis